# How to have a different layout at AppComponent level?

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have created an app that has a menu in the AppComponent which means all child pages/components will have it according to the next pseudo code:

```
<menu></menu> <--I need this removed in the new page-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now I need a new page without the menu. How can I achieve it?

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use ngIf to hide it, or put the menu in another child component which would have another router-outlet to display any of the children that need to be displayed with a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more common that you'd think, scenarios such as having an `app.component.html` side menu that you'd want to hide on `login.component` or `register.component` have the behaviour you're looking to achieve.

They way I particularly do it, is having an `@injectable({})` service I call `menu.service`, which is passed down to components as needed.

Try the following:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="appComponent">
   <div class="sideMenu" *ngIf="menuService.show">
          ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**menu.service**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MenuService {
    public shown = false;
    constructor(){}

    setShown(bool:boolean){
        this.shown = bool;
    }    
}
```

This menu service can be injected on your component's constructor that you want to hide, and can be toggled in / out with onInit & onDestroy handlers

**no-menu.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class NoMenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(public menuService: MenuService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menuService.setShown(false);
    }
    ngOnDestroy(){
        // Recovers menu on exiting component
        this.menuService.setShown(true);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you out, you can adapt it to your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

I made you a [small app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvzh5p) to show you how to implement your behavior

## EDIT

*explanations*

You create a service and inject the service in your app.component. You will use this service in your app.component.html to display the menu or not, according to the observable value you subscribe on.

When you need to hide/show your menu, you use *lifecycle hooks* `OnInit` and `OnDestroy`.

- OnInit : the component needs to hide the menum, use your service.
- OnDestroy the component no longer exists, you need to bring back the menu, use your service.